# How to access a certain entry in a csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file `hello.csv` with a cik-numbers in the third column. Now I have second file `cik.csv` where are the related companies (in column 4) to the cik-numbers (in column 1) and I want to have a list with the related companies to the cik-numbers in `hello.csv`.

I tried it with a loop:

```
with open('hello.csv', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as csvfile:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    list1=list(readCSV)
    b=-1
    for j in list1:
        b=b+1
        if b>0:
            cik=j[2] 
            with open('cik.csv', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as csvfile:
                readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                list2=list(readCSV)
```

I don't now how find my cik in the csv-file `cik.csv` and get the related company. Can I use pandas there ?

Comment: I did't get you. Please show me your csv files.

Comment: Please add input and expected output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56035620/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas` to read in the two .csv files and map the respective values:

```py
import pandas as pd

## create some dummy data
hello_csv="""
a,b,cik_numbers,d
'test',1,12, 5
'var', 6, 2, 0.1
"""

cik_csv="""
cik_numbers,b,c,related_companies
12,1,12, 'Apple'
13,6,20, 'Microsoft'
 2,1,712,'Google'
"""

## note: you would rather give this a path to your csv files
#  like: df_hello=pd.read_csv('/the/path/to/hello.csv')

df_hello=pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(hello_csv))
df_cik=pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(cik_csv))

## and add a new column to df_hello based on a mapping of cik_numbers
df_hello['related_companies'] = df_hello['cik_numbers'].map(df_cik.set_index('cik_numbers')['related_companies'])

print(df_hello)
```

yields:

```
        a  b  cik_numbers    d related_companies
0  'test'  1           12  5.0           'Apple'
1   'var'  6            2  0.1          'Google'
```

Comment: I use ```df_hello=pd.read_csv('/desktop/hello.csv')```, so i have really big data frame. What do i have to write instead of ['related_companies'] and so on when I want to have cik by cik from the `hello.csv` file the related companies which I can find in the `cik.csv` file?

Comment: @Torb well you would have to use the actual names of the columns, no? If you use `df_hello=pd.read_csv('/desktop/hello.csv')` and `df_cik=pd.read_csv('/desktop/cik.csv')`, you can inspect both `print(df_hello.columns)` and `print(df_cik.columns)` to see what `pandas` has chosen as column names; this could either be integer indices (i.e. 0,1,2,..) or headers from your .csv file (i.e. the first line, see how `pandas` chose the first lines of `cik_csv` and `hello_csv` as column names within my answer).

Comment: ok that works but i became 'NaN' for every cik_number.. something went wrong .. but thank you for your help!